# Spring @PathVariable annotation not working

Tags: java, spring

I have tried adding the @PathVariable annotation to my getmapping so that instead of going to the ../update-passwordpage, they have to go through /update-password/{id}. I just tried testing this by adding the @PathVariable in but when I try go ../update-password/test for example, it just doesn't load the page.

Is there something else I need to add, do I need to add this in the @PostMapping as well?

```
@Controller
public class UpdatePasswordController {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UpdatePasswordController.class);

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    Optional<User> testUser;
    User currentUser;



    /**
     * Gets update password form to be displayed
     * @param model
     * @return
     */
    @GetMapping("/update-password/{id}")
    public String updatePasswordForm(@PathVariable String id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        model.addAttribute("updatePasswordForm", new UpdatePasswordForm());
        model.addAttribute("httpServletRequest",request);
        logger.info("this is id");
        logger.info(id);
        return "updatePassword";
    }

    @PostMapping("/update-password")
    public String submitEmail(
            @RequestParam("password") String password,
            @Validated UpdatePasswordForm updatePasswordForm,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

      
      
        model.addAttribute("httpServletRequest",request);


        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            model.addAttribute("submitted_form", null);
            return "updatePassword";
        }


        currentUser.setPassword(password);
        userService.updateOrAddUser(currentUser);


        return "login";
    }



}
```

It also gives me this message in the logs sometimes, not sure if it is related: `Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]`

Comment: Why do you need it? Also you should post a relevant code to your problem. Just posting a error message doesn't help.

Comment: I want the user to be able to access the page via a token they are given. I have already given the code where I am having the problem

Comment: Check your question text. Apparently you are calling 'update-form' but the mapping you have defined is for 'update-password'.

Comment: Sorry I have updated this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to map the path variable explicitly? Might help.

Can you try changing this:

```
@GetMapping("/update-password/{id}")
public String updatePasswordForm(@PathVariable String id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
```

to:

```
@GetMapping("/update-password/{id}")
public String updatePasswordForm(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
```

or

```
@GetMapping("/update-password/id/{id}")
public String updatePasswordForm(@PathVariable String id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
```

Comment: Fixed but it actually was from another problem, thanks for the help

Comment: @GrandSkunk Glad it is resolved.